# Dice que envió el correo, pero no veo nada en la bandeja

Tags: php, email

Encontré este código por ahí:

```
   <?php
    if(isset($_POST['remitente']) &&
            isset($_POST['correo']))
    {
        $remitente = $_POST['remitente'];
        $correo = $_POST['correo'];

        $mail = "Prueba de mensaje";
        //Titulo
        $titulo = "PRUEBA DE TITULO";
        //cabecera
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
        //dirección del remitente 
        //$headers .= "From: Geeky Theory < tu_dirección_email >\r\n";
        $headers .= $remitente;
        //Enviamos el mensaje a tu_dirección_email 
        $bool = mail($correo,$titulo,$mail,$headers);
        if($bool){
            echo "Mensaje enviado";
        }else{
            echo "Mensaje no enviado";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "Variable no definida";
    }


?>
```

Supuestamente envía un correo, pero en la bandeja de entrada no veo nada.

Comment: El problema es que `mail` devuelve verdadero en cuanto el correo haya sido aceptado para el envío (es decir, cuando se envía el mensaje al servidor de correo), pero eso no quiere decir que ese servidor de correo lo haya enviado (hay alguna pregunta ya en el sitio donde se explica esto) y hay varios motivos por los que podría no enviarse como que haya algún valor incorrecto o que ese servidor de correo hay sido bloqueado por spam. Si tienes control sobre el servidor de correo, comprueba los logs para ver qué ocurrió con el mensaje, y si tienes acceso al email recipiente, mira la carpeta de spam

Answer (score 0):

Buenos días te dejo un ejemplo que me funciona sin problema. Si esto tampoco te funciona tendrás que comprobar que la función mail() de PHP este activada.

```
if(filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'formContacto')){
    echo "entra";
    setlocale(LC_TIME,"es_ES");
    // Destinatario y asunto
    $email_to = "tucorreo@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "Contacte desde la página de Contacte i Reserves";

    if(!isset($_POST['nombre']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telefono']) ||
        !isset($_POST['mail']) ||
        !isset($_POST['asunto'])) {

        echo "<b>Ocurrió un error y el formulario no ha sido enviado. </b><br />";
        echo "Por favor, vuelva atrás y verifique la información ingresada<br />";
        die();
    }

    $email_message = "<html><head><title>Formulari Contacte i Reserves el Pou</title></head>";
    $email_message .= "<body>";
    $email_message .= "<h1>Formulari Contacte i Reserves el Pou</h1>";
    $email_message .= "<p><b>Nom: </b>".$_POST['nombre'];
    $email_message .= "</p><p><b>Correu: </b>".$_POST['mail'];
    $email_message .= "</p><p><b>Telefono: </b>".$_POST['telefono'];
    $email_message .= "</p><p><b>Asumpte: </b>".$_POST['asunto'];
    $email_message .= "</p><p><b>Data i hora: </b>";
    $email_message .= strftime("Girona,  %d de %B del %Y a las %H:%M");
    $email_message .="</p></body>";
    $email_message .="</html>";
    // Creamos las cabeceras
    $headers = 'From: '.$_POST['mail']."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$email_to."\r\n" .
    'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n".
    'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n".
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    // Ahora se envía el e-mail usando la función mail() de PHP
    if (mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers)) {
         echo "<script language='javascript'>
            alert('Mensaje enviado, muchas gracias.');
         </script>";
    } else {
         echo "<script language='javascript'>
            alert('fallado');
         </script>";
    }

    echo "¡El formulario se ha enviado con éxito!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Haz una prueba más simple:

```
<?php
// El mensaje
$mensaje = "Línea 1\r\nLínea 2\r\nLínea 3";

/* Si cualquier línea es más larga de 70 caracteres, se debería usar wordwrap() */
$mensaje = wordwrap($mensaje, 70, "\r\n");

// Enviarlo
mail('caffeinated@example.com', 'Mi título', $mensaje);
?>
```

Si sigue sin funcionarte sería necesario conocer en qué entorno estás ejecutando el código.